# TFS Scheduled Backup Retry

Tags: tfs, database-backups

Is there a way to configure the TFS Scheduled backups to perform a retry if the backup fails? Specifically for full backups.

We're having problems with contention for resources and it fails and gives up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't the feature in TFS backup, we cannot achieve that.

I help you submitted a user voice here:
https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/20070241-retry-the-backup-when-a-scheduled-backup-failed

You can go there and vote it up to achieve that in future.